# How to redirect to home page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, user-controls, webusercontrol

How can I redirect a user to home page?

Example: `mywebsite.example/ddfdf/fdfdsf` and I want to redirect to `mywebsite.example`

However I want to do it without typing the static name. How can I do this?

Comment: Question could be better worded to include "with Javascript" or "using Javascript" if that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
document.location.href="/";
```

Comment: <span href='document.location.href="/";'>Go to homepage</span> or put it into a function and call it when he clicks on something

Answer (score 41):

```
document.location.href="/";
```

or

```
 window.location.href = "/";
```

According to the W3C, they are the same. In reality, for cross browser safety, you should use `window.location` rather than `document.location`.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#window-location

(**Note**: I copied the difference explanation above, from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip).)

Answer (score 10):

```
window.location.href = "/";
```

This worked for me.
If you have multiple folders/directories, you can use this:

```
window.location.href = "/folder_name/";
```

Answer (score 6):

Can you do this on the server, using Apache's mod_rewrite for example? If not, you can use the [`window.location.replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to erase the current URL from the back/forward history (to not break the back button) and go to the root of the web site:

```
window.location.replace('/');
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe

```
var re = /^https?:\/\/[^/]+/i;
window.location.href = re.exec(window.location.href)[0];
```

is what you're looking for?

Comment: This will break the back button if it is done automatically on page load.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location = '/';
```

Should usually do the trick, but it depends on your sites directories. This will work for your example

Answer (score 0):

`strRetMsg ="<script>window.location.href = '../Other/Home.htm';</script>";`

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", strRetMsg,false);`

Put this code in Page Load.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = location.href;
var newurl = url.replace('some-domain.example','another-domain.example';);
location.href=newurl;
```

See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291014/3901511

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = location.href;
var newurl = url.replace('some-domain.example','another-domain.example';);
location.href=newurl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to home page with the code below. *[location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) and [location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) redirect to the URL adding the record to the history so we can go back to the previous page while [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) redirects to the URL not adding the record to the history so we cannot go back to the previous page:

```
location="/";
location.href="/";
location.assign("/");
location.replace("/");
```