# Jetty config to redirect all 404s to home page

Tags: java, jetty

Google has cached some old URLs to pages that no longer exist on a site. I'd like to redirect any 404 pages to the home page.

I have a jetty installation with a ROOT.war file installed in jetty/webapps. The ROOT.war file contains a WEB-INF/web.xml file that has the following in it:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

However, this is only redirecting top level files, nothing in subdirectories. So the following URL get redirected to the home page:

```
http://mysite.com/pageDoesntExist.html
```

But this one doesn't and just gives a 404 error:

```
http://mysite.com/directoryDoesntExist/pageDoesntExist.html
```

Is there a way to configure all 404's to go to the home page? Can I do this in the jetty/contexts directory somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the org.mortbay.jetty.handler.MovedContextHandler: 
http://jetty.mortbay.org/xref/org/mortbay/jetty/handler/MovedContextHandler.html

Bots will use the Header 301 Redirect to update the cache google

Comment: Thanks. But I'm unclear on how to configure it to handle lots of URLs. I'm having to create a new context file for every single URL, which is crazy. There must be a better way. Can you provide an example, for instance to redirect all addresses in the `/directoryDoesntExist` directory to the home page?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

(as described in [Redirecting a 404 error page to a custom page of my Spring MVC webapp in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780257))
and then inside `error404.html` do a redirect:

```
<html>
<head><title>Redirecting...</title></head>
<body>
    <script>
    document.location.href="/";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(as described in [how to redirect to home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231605))