# Redirecting a 404 error page to a custom page of my Spring MVC webapp in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am working with tomcat 7 and I've built and deployed a Spring MVC webapp in tomcat 7 and it's working perfectly fine. What I want is that, whenever a 404 error occurs on my server, it should be redirected to a custom page which I have built in my webapp. I have configured my webapp as a default webapp in tomcat.

I have tried doing this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/templates/error/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

But all in vain.

Glad if someone can help me out in this.

Comment: I don't think you will need /WEB-INF

Comment: I tried without /WEB_INF also.But its not working.I am not getting the default 404 error page but not even redirected to my custom page also.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code> 
    <location>error404</location>
</error-page>
```

And then:

```java
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error404")
    protected String error404() {
        return "/templates/error/error.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dejel The first one tells the server to redirect the 404 HTTP error code to the `error404` URL. The second manages the new request for the URL `error404`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already working in `WEB-INF`(web.xml) folder,You need not to mention `WEB-INF`.

```
<error-page> <error-code>404</error-code> 
        <location>/templates/error/error.html</location>
                                                 </error-page>
```

Check this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml) also.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am still facing the same problem. Neither I am getting the default page nor I am redirected to my Custom page. I did this change in web.xml of the tomcat in $CATALINA_HOME/conf .

Comment: @Hitesh Why you changed in tomcats web.xml??I'm talking about your project's web.xml.Your project don't have any `web.xml`  file ??You should do in your projects web.xml  not tomcat's one.

Comment: Yes I do have and I tried in that also by embedding the above written code just before the </web-app> tag.But that also doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **WEB-INF folder > views**.

Create a page for example : error_404.jsp.

Now you have to create a controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String error_404(){
    return "error_404";
}
```

Now edit your web.xml file and edit it like this :

```
<error-page> 
  <error-code>404</error-code> 
  <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: You just have to change "403" with "404".