# What's the best way to redirect a Tomcat 404 URL with Apache as front-end?

Tags: apache, tomcat, guacamole

I have Apache 2.4 forwarding *:80 traffic to my sole Tomcat 7.0 webapp (Guacamole) like so:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/guacamole/
ProxyPassReverse / http:/localhost:8080/guacamole/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / http://localhost:8080/guacamole
```

This works, except when I log out of the webapp, I get the following 404 as reported by Tomcat:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /guacamole/guacamole/index.xhtml
```

From what I've read I've got several options, including using ProxyPass/redirect, rewrite, VirtualHost, and symlinks. Some of these options are possible under both Apache and Tomcat configs. I'm confused. What's the best method to ensure `/guacamole/guacamole/index.xhtml` (or *) requests get to to `/guacamole/index.xhtml`?

(I know no Java if the actual root cause is in the Guacamole webapp code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles across this issue, I was able to resolve from Suresh Atta's answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780257/redirecting-a-404-error-page-to-a-custom-page-of-my-sring-mvc-webapp-in-tomcat).

Basically all that I had to do was create a custom 404 html in /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/logout.html which contains a polite message and invitation to log in again:

```
<html>
<h2 align=center>Thank you. You're now logged out.</h2>
<h2 align=center>If this was a mistake or you'd like to begin a new session, 
please <a href="http://guacamoleapp.address.com">click here.</a></h2>
</html>
```

And then I added this directive to web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/logout.html</location>
</error-page>
```

I'm sure there's a little cleaner way to do this, but the requirements are low for this right now, and this smoothed the rough edge.