# Issue with m=1 and m=0 redirects

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

Recently I moved my website from Blogger to own host with Apache ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958116/301-redirect-blogger-to-another-host-and-keep-google-rank)).

After migrating and make the necessary 301 redirects, I deleted that Blogger site. However, I'm receiving several alerts "404 Page Not Found" in Google Webmasters Tools. Most are related to the old urls for mobile devices, example: **example.com/2015/oldurl.html?m=1** and **example.com/2015/oldurl.html?m=0**

There is a method to force a 301 redirect these mobile URLs for my home page or another page hosted on the new host? Maybe some command in .htaccess?

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/? [L,R=301]
```