# Change Phonegap User Agent

Tags: ios, cordova, user-agent

My Phonegap application is allowed to browse to some external sites that also use the Phonegap API.  Currently I am conditionally including the Phonegap javascript based on what platform you are on (Android, iOS, etc).  However, I can't tell the difference between Phonegap applications and the regular browser on a mobile device.  Is there a way to change the user agent in my Phonegap app to give my server a hint about this?

Most interested in the iOS solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32337353/817202) to a similar question also mentions a preference available in current Cordova versions:

```xml
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="MyCordovaApp/1.2.3" />
```

It is [documented for Android](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html) and [iOS](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html).

Answer (score 18):

If you're still looking for a quick solution for that one, this is how I achieved it:

```
// Modify the user-agent
NSString* suffixUA = @" my nice user-agent suffix";
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
NSString* defaultUA = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
NSString* finalUA = [defaultUA stringByAppendingString:suffixUA];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:finalUA, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

In the Phonegap (Cordova) sample app, you need to add these lines in the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method of *AppDelegate.m*

I spent an entire day trying to figure this one out! I'm sure it could be useful to other people.

Comment: Would be nice to include the android solution too.

Comment: I found the Android solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406393/change-phonegap-cordova-user-agent-for-ajax

Comment: To get @alanou solution working you should add the code he posted at the end of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method just before the return statement. It seems that [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; must run before you can change the UA. Test OK on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3

Answer (score 6):

[CB-2520](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2520) was resolved, which proposed allowing the user-agent string to be modified.  You can achieve this now by setting the *baseUserAgent* property of the MainViewController. For a simple test, you can add the following to the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method of the **AppDelegate.m**, after the MainViewController is initialized:

`self.viewController.baseUserAgent = @"My Custom User Agent";`

Comment: This doesn't have any effect when I set it...what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a more powerful http client for cordova that allows changing the user agent, or any header in that matter, try out https://github.com/aporat/cordova-plugin-fetch. it wraps around well tested native networking libraries (`AFNetworking 2` on ios, and `OKHttp` on android).

it also follows the window.fetch, so you could use `cordovaFetch` on the simulators and devices, while testing on the browser with `fetch.js`.

Just install the plugin with

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/aporat/cordova-plugin-fetch.git`

and include the user agent header in any request you made.

```
cordovaFetch('/users.json', {
  method : 'GET',
  headers: {
   'User-Agent': 'your user agent'
 },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Detect between a mobile browser or a PhoneGap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347539/detect-between-a-mobile-browser-or-a-phonegap-application/10572142#10572142)

I made a contribution but there are plenty of answers which may be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work in iOS using Cordova 3.3, presumably because of [CB-2520](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2520) but, as a hack, I modified `CDVViewController`.h to make the `userAgent` property readwrite, and then simply updated self.userAgent in the `viewDidLoad` of my controller that inherits from `CDVViewController`.

If timing is an issue, you could forcibly manipulate the `userAgent` lazy-loaded property in `CDVViewController.m`.

Both of these are very dirty.  :)

Comment: [CB-2520](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2520) has been resolved; CDVViewController now has a baseUserAgent property that can be modified