# Change PhoneGap / Cordova User-Agent for AJAX

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, user-agent

I'm using phonegap / cordova for developing an Android app.

The app has to read files on a remote server. Therefore I'm using AJAX (jQuery).
The problem is: The remote server redirects all connections from mobile devices to a mobile version, which doesn't work for me, so I have to change the User Agent to a desktop browser.

How can I do this? I've seen [a solution for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624259/change-phonegap-user-agent). Is something like this possible for Android?

---

**Edit:**
I found a solution myself:

Just add

```
WebSettings w = this.appView.getSettings();      
w.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1");
```

to `/src/com/a/b/c.java` in `onCreate`-method.

Comment: This did not work for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question - you don't have to edit it in to the question itself. It would be a lot neater if you edit again and did that.

Comment: @ninov I am using Cordova but I don't have any .java file. Can we call this from javascript? Does it still work as of 2017?

Answer (score 10):

put this in your onCreate method: (after super.init();)

```
super.appView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Your own agent string");
```

this worked for me.

See for more settings: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a more powerful http client for cordova that allows changing the user agent, or any header in that matter, try out https://github.com/aporat/cordova-plugin-fetch. it wraps around well tested native networking libraries (`AFNetworking 2` on ios, and `OKHttp` on android).

it also follows the window.fetch, so you could use `cordovaFetch` on the simulators and devices, while testing on the browser with `fetch.js`.

Just install the plugin with

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/aporat/cordova-plugin-fetch.git`

and include the user agent header in any request you made.

```
cordovaFetch('/users.json', {
  method : 'GET',
  headers: {
   'User-Agent': 'your user agent'
 },
})
```