# Android: Block Adsense ads in WebView with admob

Tags: android, webview, admob, adsense

I have a website with adsense and secondly I have an android webview with that site application, this application has a admob banner and adsense block need not to generate conflict, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in phonegap/cordova, use this [cordova and phonegap AdMob plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) to show AdMob ads.

Then you have 2 options:

- Remove the adsense divs via javascript inside the app (show us your website code in order to give you more accurate help)
- If you have access to the server from wich the content is being shown, render the content without the divs that contains adsense. You can use User Agent to render the content. (again show us the code which is rendering the page to help you more accurately)

If possible I recommend using the second option (less traffic and more consistent). In your server you can know that you are in your mobile app from the User Agent string. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406393/change-phonegap-cordova-user-agent-for-ajax) to setup user agent in Cordova/Phonegap.

If you are not using Cordova/Phonegap, firstly I would recommend you to use it and your live will be easier :), otherwise you should override the user agent string in the code. See [android user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586197/android-user-agent) and
[UIWebView iOS5 changing user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent)