# Attempting to change navigator.userAgent using Cordova for Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to all of this, so I am probably missing something pretty obvious, but I am trying to change the userAgent string in an application I am building with Cordova.  Based upon the documentation at the Cordova website, it would appear that I should only need to add the following to my config.xml file:

preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="My string value here"

So I included this line in my config.xml and then added this code to my javascript in my cordova app:

var ua = navigator.userAgent;

alert(ua);

I then build the project and install it on my android phone.  However, when I run the app I get the same userAgent reported back by my alert regardless of whether I included  preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="My string value here"  in the config.xml or not.  I am using version 5 of Cordova (5.3.1 I believe) and this config.xml fix was listed in the documentation for version 5.1.1 on the Cordova website.

I have also seen another possible fix on stackoverflow in the following post:

[Change PhoneGap / Cordova User-Agent for AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406393/change-phonegap-cordova-user-agent-for-ajax)

Specifically I am looking at the response that recommends:

put this in your onCreate method: (after super.init();)
super.appView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Your own agent string");

I am sorry to ask such a basic question, but how to I carry this out?  Is it possible to do this while still using the Cordova CLI or do I need to import the project into Android studio first?  Where exactly do I find the onCreate method that I need to modify.

Thank you for any help you may be able to offer.

Comment: how apps have you done? It appears while you are taking the right steps, you have not read the correct pieces of documentation.

Comment: try waiting for deviceready event before checking the user agent

Comment: jcesamible:  I added the following code and still the same result:

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert(navigator.userAgent);
}

I am pretty sure the problem is that I am not doing this using the in app browser, but in the body of the main app.  I think that I need to go the second route mentioned in my post, which means I need to modify the onCreate method.