# How to change user-agent on Cordova(Phonegap) 2.4.0 for iOS?

Tags: cordova, user-agent

I'm wondering how to change user-agent on Cordova(Phonegap) 2.4.0 for iOS.

I've already read the solution for changing user-agent for iOS.
[Change Phonegap User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624259/change-phonegap-user-agent)

But it's not working on 2.4.0. :p

I think there are some changes for user-agent regarding InAppBrowser functionality...
But I can't find out why upper code isn't working.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats true, the User-Agent handling changed a little bit since 2.4. All the magic happens now in the *CDVUserAgentUtil* class. Currently Cordova does not provide any standard way to override/extend the User-Agent (but they have it on the roadmap: see [CB-2520](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2520).

Anyhow, I created this workaround which worked fine for me on Version 2.5:
(I placed the snippet in the *AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function*)

**Note: Cordova saves the agent in the user settings when the app starts the first time or the local changes. We just need to override the default settings before Cordova creates a cached copy of it. If there is a cache available we do not need to run this code again.**

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *isAgentDefined = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"Cordova-User-Agent"];

if(isAgentDefined == nil) {
    UIWebView* sampleWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    NSString *defaultAgent = [sampleWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
    [sampleWebView release];
    NSString *myAgent = @"My custom User-Agent";
    NSString *userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", defaultAgent, myAgent];

    [CDVUserAgentUtil acquireLock:^(NSInteger lockToken) {
        [CDVUserAgentUtil setUserAgent:userAgent lockToken:lockToken];
        [CDVUserAgentUtil releaseLock:&lockToken];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi, edited your answer by adding ```#import``` statement to get it compiling. Trying to see if that works and in index.html of Cordova app put ```<input type="text" id="url" value="http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/"><input type="button" value="go" onClick="window.location=document.getElementById('url').value">``` but the User-Agent string does not include "My custom User-Agent" - any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I know this dates from 2013 but I wanted to ask @andreast00, I have the problem where the user-agent successfully changes but only the first time I open my app. How can I make the app not cache it or clear the cache once I exit?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on iOS in Cordova 3.3, and [CB-2520](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2520) still exists, so I hacked the userAgent property in CDVViewController.m, which is very dirty obviously, but worked.