# Changing User-Agent in phonegap app works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cordova

I have a PhoneGap 3.0 app that I have built on the IOS platform.

I have added the following two lines to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate.m` to attempt to spoof a particular user agent (after looking through numerous SO questions):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"my custom user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

When I run the app in the IOS simulator and inspect `navigator.userAgent`, I get the expected "my custom user agent" as the output.

When I do a remote phonegap build, run the app on my iPhone and inspect `navigator.userAgent`, I get the standard iPhone user agent, not my custom one.

Why am I getting different outputs from `navigator.userAgent` on the simulator and my device?

Related SO questions:

[Change Phonegap User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624259/change-phonegap-user-agent)

[Detect between a mobile browser or a PhoneGap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347539/detect-between-a-mobile-browser-or-a-phonegap-application/10572142#10572142)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting different outputs from navigator.userAgent on the simulator and my device?

When we do a remote phonegap build, we're effectively zipping up the assets of the project and uploading them, so any changes we make to files outside the `www` directory of the project are ignored.

The phonegap build service is doing its own build and creating its own `AppDelegate.m`, without the changes to edit the user agent, which explains why we're not seeing the custom user agent on the device and we are seeing it on the simulator.