# Cordova/PhoneGap "deviceReady" event is not fired in IOS 7 when Device plugin is added and user agent is modified

Tags: events, plugins, cordova

I got a problem with "deviceReady" event not fired in the combination of the following situation

1) IOS 7 (Android 4.4 tested ok)

2) Using Cordova 3.1.0 or 3.2.0

3) overwrite ( note not appending, basically changed the whole user agent string to some arbitrary string)the user agent natively following the instruction here [Change Phonegap User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624259/change-phonegap-user-agent)
(I can confirmed the user agent is modified by reading navigator.useragent)

4) Add org.apache.cordova.device plugin

If I removed Device plugin, but still loads other plugins like PushPlugin and globalization, "deviceReady" fired ok.

Try to step through the cordova IOS native code, but at this stage it does not reveal much.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: even I am facing the same issue.r u getting alert() fired inside the function of device.ready.I am using cordova 2.9

Comment: Can you update to the latest version of everything? (xCode, cordova, and the device plugin)