# Is fastclick.js implemented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, fastclick.js

The problem I am encountering is that when I test the 300 ms delay by clicking on some buttons on a website, I notice no delay. But when I load the application too phonegap, then I touch the buttons on a tablet, I notice the 300 ms delay directly.. So I am kinda confused that I notice the delay with phonegap but almost nothing when test in on a website... So I wish to check either by using alert or something else that fastclick.js is working on a website, before I load it too phonegap? This will save me time.

I have included this in my main index.html file, [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type='application/javascript' src='js/fastclick.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    new FastClick(document.body);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Fastclick` performs browser detection using the `user agent` string. In your phonegap app the `user agent` is different from what a mobile browser would return and thus the `fastclick` script does not detect that you're on a mobile device. You can modify the `user agent` and the way to do that is described in the answers on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624259/change-phonegap-user-agent).