# Setting User-Agent request header in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, http, mobile, typescript

I am building a Cordova-based app in Typescript and I need to send an HTTP GET request to a NTRIP Caster. Though a fairly simple procedure, the NTRIP Caster requires that the User-Agent request header be set to "NTRIP (something)" or it will reject the request.

Unfortunately, it seems I cannot change the header via a simple XMLHttpRequest without getting a **Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"** error due to browser restrictions. I've also tried Angular's $http.get and even jQuery, with no luck.

What are my alternatives? Is there a cordova plugin I should be using, or some library/wrapper I can use?

I am very new to Cordova and JS in general so bear with me -- I might follow up with some inane questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [How i can set User Agent in Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052221/how-i-can-set-user-agent-in-cordova-app)

Basically, set the following in config.xml:

```
preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value= "NTRIP/whatever" />
```

Alternatively, I found this Cordova plugin that claims to do the same, but I haven't tested it:

https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent