# Cordova - In-App Browser to show website as desktop view

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I was creating a Cordova (android) application in which I am using the In-App Browser plugin. I want the website in it to show as desktop view. I tried changing the user-agent with the `<preference>` ([How i can set User Agent in Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052221/how-i-can-set-user-agent-in-cordova-app)) tag in the config.xml file which is actually changing but it doesn't seem to be affecting the website state. I tried Googling that but I found nothing that could solve my problem. If you solved my issue, it would be really great if you could upload an apk for proof: please don't reply if you haven't tested your solution.

EDIT:
The problem is that the user-agent works only the first time you open the app... You have to clear the cache and open the app again so it works.

Comment: which website are you trying to load? some of them don't check the user agent, but use responsive design.

Comment: Check the edit ;)

Comment: so it's a bug. Report it at issues.cordova.io, and the website is still helpful