# Using the same codebase for phonegap and web?

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

Is it wise to use the same codebase for our mobile web app and phonegap app? They are meant to be similar, the phonegap version just lets us do more. Can we detect if it's not running on phonegap and sequester calls to the phonegap api or does it make more sense to separate them.

Comment: you'll bound to run into maintenance hell sooner or later, I suggest, don't... :S

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347539/detect-between-a-mobile-browser-or-a-phonegap-application/10348353#10348353

Answer (score 17):

Sure, you can use most of the same codebase.
Some phonegap APIs are the same in html5 (for instance localStorage) so there's no difference in code there.

If you're using phonegap Build service, it will add the phonegap.js / cordova.js script file to your project root. Just include it in your html all the time. Then you can detect whether your application is running within phonegap:

```
var isPhonegap = function() {
  return (typeof(cordova) !== 'undefined' || typeof(phonegap) !== 'undefined');
}

if (isPhonegap()) {
  // phonegap.js/cordova.js exists.. now let's handle the onDeviceReady event
} else {
  // in-browser
}
```

If you need some common startup code, put it in a function and call this function from the onDeviceReady handler and the *else* block above.

If the phonegap api you're calling doesn't have the exact same name as the html5 one (because it has the Moz* or WebKit* prefix for instance), just wrap both inside a new name. For instance:

```
var requestFileSystem = (isPhonegap() ? requestFileSystem : window.WebKitRequestFileSystem);
```

If the phonegap API you're using really has no html5 equivalent, try to duplicate the functionality yourself in javascript if possible, otherwise you'll just lose the functionality in your browser. But make sure it degrades gracefully enough without that feature.

Note: to test the mobile devices features like accelerometer, geolocation, etc.. in your browser checkout the [Ripple Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc).

Comment: very usefull, just a comment: in line 5 there is a mistake is not "iPhonegap" it has to be "isPhonegap". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to keep the web codebase intact...

The current problem with using the built in deviceready event, is that when the page is loaded, you have no way of telling the app: "Hey this is NOT running on an mobile device, there's no need to wait for the device to be ready to start".

1. In the native portion of the code, for example for iOS, in MainViewController.m there's a method viewDidLoad, I am sending a javascript variable that I later check for in the web code, if that variable is around, I will wait to start the code for my page until everything is ready (for example, navigator geolocation)

   Under MainViewController.m:

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isAppNative = true;"];
       [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
   }
   ```
2. index.html the code goes like this:

   ```
   function onBodyLoad()
   {
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   }

   function onDeviceReady(){;
       myApp.run();
   }

   try{
       if(isAppNative!=undefined);
   }catch(err){
       $(document).ready(function(){
           myApp.run();
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same codebase. The whole point of PhoneGap is to convert your mobile sites into apps. It isn't that difficult to detect features and screen realestate as appropriate. The trouble with seperate codebases is usually the cost of double-handling your content and styles. If necessary you could separate those out into a shared resource and bundle them at runtime/access but personally I'd still go with keeping it all together.

This blog covers the detection issue (see the comments too): http://bennolan.com/2011/08/22/phonegap-detection.html. The crux of it though is `if (window.PhoneGap){...}`