# detecting phonegap in meteor

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

Right now I'm building an app in the Meteor JS framework -- an app that can run both from a browser as well as be packaged with Cordova Phonegap for iOS / Android use.

I would like to be able to detect if I am in Cordova or not. I still want to distinguish between mobile browser and mobile PhoneGap usage.

[Detect between a mobile browser or a PhoneGap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347539/detect-between-a-mobile-browser-or-a-phonegap-application) doesn't make sense for me as I am still loading the Meteor app via an HTTP call.

How else could I detect if the user is loading our app from PhoneGap or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could always check up if the deviceready handlers get initiated and use a session hash to store this e.g

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    Session.set("isphonegap",true);
}, false);
```

You can use this reactively e.g

```
Deps.autorun() {
    if(Session.equals("isphonegap", true)) {
         //Yes its phonegap!
    }
}
```

The only thing is you have to assume its always not phonegap, and if `deviceready` fires (on a device within phonegap/cordova) then you can check with `Session.get("isphonegap")` whether the device is using phonegap in your template helpers or anywhere else reactive variables can run

Answer (score 3):

Today it's much easier:

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  console.log("Printed only in mobile cordova apps");
}
```

[Meteor Docs: Adding Cordova/Phonegap-specific Javascript code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#adding-cordovaphonegap-specific-javascript-code-to-your-application)