# initializing phonegap by deviceready event using require.js

Tags: cordova, requirejs

I'd like to find a way to initialize my app by the deviceready event I'm listening on.

I have this javascript files to be loaded:

```
//index.html
<head>
    <script src="cordova.js">
    <script src="require.js" data-main="main.js">
</head>
```

Now I'd like to call a function of main.js to start initializing my app, after the device really is ready. But I don't have any access because it's a requirejs module.

```
//index.html
<body>
    <script>
         function onDeviceReady() {
              //main.js initialize my app
         }
    </script>
</body>
```

It'd be great to be able to call a function inside main.js like this:

```
//main.js
var myApp = {};
define(['app'],
    function(app){
       var init = function(){
             app.run();
        }
        myApp.init = init;
    }
);
```

Than back in my index.html:

```
<body>
    <script>
         function onDeviceReady() {
             myApp.init();
         }
    </script>
 </body>
```

I don't know if this'd work.
How do you initialize your phonegap app using requirejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event listener could be added inside my main module.
So the app becomes initialized by the deviceready event of the main module like this:

```
require([
'config/RootPathConfig',
'app',
'overrides'
], function(rootPath, app){

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("deviceReady");
        rootPath.initialize();
        app.init();                         //now the app content is loaded after the device is ready :)
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this aproach is that it pollutes the
global namespace, and it's overly complex. Why not just require
app in your device ready callback?

```
<body>
    <script>
         function onDeviceReady() {
           require(['app'], function(App) {
             app.init()
           } 
         }
    </script>
</body>
```

Then you don't even need main.js! (unless you want to add some
configuration).

Comment: I guess the problem would be that require.js needs a module as xyz.js as reference to be applied. So I need the main.js (module) due to the relation here:  <script src="require.js" data-main="main.js">

Comment: The data-main attribute is optional. You're welcome to use it and put configuration info in the file main.js, but only if needed.

Comment: So I could leave it blank? I'll try that out tomorrow. So far thx alot .

Comment: Leaving data-main of <script src="require.js" data-main="main.js"> empty doesn't work unfortunately. It doesn't load anything then.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a promise:

*onDeviceReady.js*

```js
define(function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
    if (document.URL.match(/^https?:/i)) { // credits to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12255930/1225328
      console.log("Running in a browser...");
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("Running in an app...");
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", resolve, false);
    }
  });
});
```

*main.js*

```js
define(["onDeviceReady", "app"], function(onDeviceReady, app) {
  onDeviceReady.then(function() {
    // device is ready, bootstrap your app:
    app.run();
  });
});
```