# (CSS)Trouble having background image resize for mobile device

Tags: css, html

```
  /* Responsive Full Background Image Using CSS
  * Tutorial URL: http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/
  */

  body {
      /* Location of the image */
      background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);
      /* Image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
      background-position: center center;
      /* Image doesn't repeat */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      /* Makes the image fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content height is greater than the image height */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      /* This is what makes the background image rescale based on its container's size */
      background-size: cover;
      /* Pick a solid background color that will be displayed while the background image is loading */
      background-color: #464646;
      /* SHORTHAND CSS NOTATION
   * background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
   */
      min-width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
  }
  /* For mobile devices */

  @media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
      .logo {
          /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
     * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
          background-image: url(images/background-photo-mobile-devices.jpg);
          height: 300px;
          width: 100%;
          background-size: contain;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: center;
      }
  }
```

The background image shows up fine on a desktop browser but when I view it on my iphone 6 plus or any other mobile phone the image doesn't scale correctly and is partially cut off. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: This [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12255930/2968762) may help you distinguish between Mobile and Web page. Accordingly you may change your `background-position` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to work on the background and make it work well:
You should delete the onset:

```css
min-width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

And

```css
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
```

The first way to make the length or width is supported on the other by adding the following code:

```css
background-size: 100% auto;
```

The second way to make the rear rubber with any size by adding the following code:

```css
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use or add for more optimization:

```
html{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

it will cover the all html or body base on the tag you want the image to cover.