# self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString does not work

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('ok');"];[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

I wrote it in cordova appdelegate.m!

Comment: what version of cordova-ios platform are you building with?

Comment: cordova -v in terminal -> 5.4.1, but Xcode console display 'Apache Cordova native platform version 3.9.2 is starting.'  when I start the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On cordova-ios@3.x you should be able to do:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

On cordova-ios@4+ you will need to cast the Webview class as it also supports WKWebView:

```
if ([self.webView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
    [(UIWebView*)self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Comment: <UIWebView: 0x14ddb1880; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x14dda85a0>>, but  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString it does not work.

Comment: That's of course assuming your class extends CDVPlugin - I'm using the [same approach in my own plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/src/ios/Diagnostic.m#L477) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

May want to try `NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithString:@"alert('ok');"];[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];`

or `NSString* jsString = @"alert('ok');"[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];`