# JQuery document.ready vs Phonegap deviceready

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am making a phonegap application with jquery. I am confused whether I should wrap my entire code inside JQuery's `$(document).ready()` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //mycode
});
```

or inside the deviceready event of phonegap like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    //mycode
});
```

I am currently using `document.ready` but I think I may encounter problems if I try to access some Phonegap API methods inside `document.ready`.

Which is the best event to wrap my code in, document.ready or deviceready?

Comment: Same kind of facing in phonegap android app. But iOS is fine. In my app blocks are not blinking in case quickly hit start button[sometimes only]!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use the deviceready event to avoid funny things happening.

The docs state:

> This is a very important event that every PhoneGap application should use.
>
> PhoneGap consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a PhoneGap JavaScript function before it is loaded.
>
> The PhoneGap deviceready event fires once PhoneGap has fully loaded. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to PhoneGap function.

Typically, you will want to attach an event listener with `document.addEventListener` once the HTML document's DOM has loaded.

Read the documentation here:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Answer (score 89):

A key point in the answer is this line from the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) of the `deviceready` event.

> This event behaves differently from others in that any event handler registered after the event has been fired will have its callback function called immediately.

What this means is that you won't 'miss' the event if you add a listener after the event has been fired.

So, first move all the initialization code to the onDeviceReady function.  Then first handle the document.ready. Within the document.ready if you determine that you are running in a browser, just call the onDeviceReady function, otherwise add the deviceready listener.  This way when you are in the onDeviceReady function you are sure that all the needed 'ready's have happened.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // are we running in native app or in a browser?
    window.isphone = false;
    if(document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1 
        && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1) {
        window.isphone = true;
    }

    if( window.isphone ) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }
});

function onDeviceReady() {
    // do everything here.
}
```

The isphone check works because in phonegap, the index.html is loaded using a `file:///` url.

Comment: I like this solution as well. In my build I add a test for localhost ```if(document.URL.indexOf("http://") == -1 && document.URL.indexOf("localhost") != 7)``` so I can open index.html locally from the file system if I want to.

Comment: If your app could run in browser with https you should also check for "https" protocol so the "if" should be: 

if (document.URL.indexOf('http://') === -1 && document.URL.indexOf('https://') === -1)

Comment: window.isphone is seems to be true for me even if running in a browser. Why would this be?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Quite possibly you are opening the html using file:/// url, i.e. by double clicking the html file in the file manager.

Comment: Not exactly.  We are depending on the behaviour of phonegap.  If we are running in a browser, we explicitly call it, and if we are running as a native app, we register a handler with phonegap.  Either way, when we are in the deviceready function we are sure that both the DOM and the device are ready.

Comment: For a more complete discussion on how to accurately detect whether you're running in phonegap, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8068052/13860)

Comment: Additionally, if you have lots of files and you don't want to change each one of them, just create a custom event that you normally (in an app) call after both the document and device are ready, and then check if you are running in a browser and if so, then just trigger that event, it is much more efficient that way.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

jQuery.ready() is using:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Source: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js

Cordova/PhoneGap instructs you to use:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Source: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html

My suggestion is, that you put all the initialization code for your Cordova/PhoneGap plugins inside the callback function which is fired when the `deviceready` event occurs. Example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kinjal's answer really helped me get on track, but I had to fight a lot of issues with timing.

I use Cordova device ready event to read data files for my app, a few JSON packets which drive interface building and are loaded by default inside the www folder, but might eventually be downloaded from a server, to upgrade the application database.

I have found a lot of issues because the application data structures had not enough time to initialize before routing was started.

I wound up with this solution: initialize jQuery first, call the event handler of Cordova at the end of jQuery initialization, call the application startup routine at the end of the last processing in Cordova initialization.

All this nightmare started because I needed a way to read template files for Hogan.js and could not read them with the file protocol and a simple XHR.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ...

    // are we running in native app or in a browser?
    window.isphone = false;
    if (document.URL.indexOf('http://') === -1 && document.URL.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
        window.isphone = true;
    }

    if (window.isphone) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }
});

function onDeviceReady() {
    function readFromFile(fileName, cb) {
        // see (https://www.neontribe.co.uk/cordova-file-plugin-examples/)
    }

    ...

    readFromFile(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/views/tappa.html', function (data) {
        app.views.lastview = data;
        app.start();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using PhoneGap Build cli-6.2.0 and when I test the procedure you suggested is doesn't do anything inside function `onDeviceReady()`.

With older versions of PGB it works!

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  window.isphone = false;
  if (document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1 && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1) { window.isphone = true }
  if (window.isphone) { document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false); } else { onDeviceReady(); }
 });
 function onDeviceReady() {
  alert( window.isphone );   
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The one does not have to exclude the other. One simple example:

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    console.log('event: device ready');
    $(document).on('pause', function() {
        console.log('event: pause');
    });
    $(document).on('resume', function() {
        console.log('event: resume');
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('deviceready', function() {} }); who ever uses that? Hmm....

Comment: The question uses it; go complain there.