# Calling an External Javascript Function

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, local-storage

I have an app i'm programming in Javascript/JQuery. I'm using PhoneGap and want to use localStorage to store the users credentials the first time they open the app and then autofill next time the user opens the app. I want to call the checkPreAuth() right when the page loads. But It's not calling my function. Can anybody help me?

Calling the function from login.html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
checkPreAuth();
});
</script>
```

And the function in my digest_auth.js:

```
function checkPreAuth() {
var form = $("#loginForm");
    var values = new Array();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    if(window.localStorage["username"] == undefined && window.localStorage["password"] == undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("username", username);
        localStorage.setItem("password", password);
        alert('Saved username and password');
    } else {
        alert(username + ', ' + password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire contents of the `digest_auth.js` file? Is that function declared globally? or is it inside of a scope.

Comment: that's all I have in the digest_auth.js file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the answer to your problem. I faced this problem and instead of using document ready of jquery, i used this:
[JQuery document.ready vs Phonegap deviceready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready)