# Data not loading when trying to integrate phonegap 3.0 and backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cordova

I have created a project using backbone and node.js.Its working fine.
But now I am trying to create an app using phonegap 3.0.
As of now, I am just trying to integrate backbone ie the client side to phonegap.
But my problem is that data is not getting loaded.I am running the server and in my backbone model, I am giving the IP address of the server.

Following is the code for model.

```
define([
'backbone',
'app/helpers/config'
], function(Backbone, config) {
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'SERVERIP:3000/deals'
});

var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    models: Model,

    initialize: function(attrs) {
        this.options = attrs;
    },

    comparator: function(deal) {
        return deal.get('rating');
    },

    url: function() {
        var url = 'SERVERIP:3000/deals';

        if (this.options.q) {
            url += '/q=' + this.options.q;
        }
        if (this.options.p) {
            url += '/s=' + (this.options.p - 1) * config.pageSize;
        } else {
            url += '/s=' + 0;
        }

        url += '/t=' + config.pageSize;

        return url;
    },

    getPageUrl: function(direction) {
        var page, url = 'serverIP:3000/deals';

        if (direction === 'next') {
            page = this.pageNumber + 1;
        } else if (direction === 'prev') {
            page = this.pageNumber > 1 ? this.pageNumber - 1 : 1;
        }

        if (this.options.q) {
            url += '/q=' + this.options.q;
        }

        return url + '/p=' + page;
    },

    parse: function(response) {
        this.total = response.totalMatchCount;
        this.skipped = response.criteria.resultsToSkip;
        this.pageNumber = Math.round(this.skipped / config.pageSize) + 1;

        return response.matches;
    }
    });

    return {
        model: Model,
        collection: Collection
    };
});
```

In the url root, I have mentioned the IP address. Could you please check and let me know why the data is not populating.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that your problem is not the url, it is where or how you call fetch(). Do you call it somewhere? Can you let us see this code?

You should not call it befor the deviceready event, otherwise strange things may happen on the mobile device, have a look at this:

[JQuery document.ready vs Phonegap deviceready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready)