# javaFX webview window.onload is fired before loadworker succeeds

Tags: webview, javafx, onload

I use a JavaFX webview in my application. With the following code I set a member after the page has been loaded

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            window.setMember("mymember", new JavaScriptBridge(this));
        }
    }
});
```

Now in javascript I can invoke `mymember.doSomething()` e.g. called when I press the button and it's executed successfully, but if I add the following code to the html

```
<script>
function startup() {
    mymember.doSomething();
}
window.onload=startup;
</script>
```

It's not executed automatically when the page is loaded. It seems like `window.onload` is executed before the `LoadWorker` gets notified. So `mymember` is not set yet. But on the other hand, I cannot set `mymember`  before the html has been loaded, right?

Any idea when I need to set `mymember` to have it ready when `window.onload` is executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's too late for an answer to this problem, but after answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715570/passing-values-to-javafx-from-javascript) question, I've been trying to find a reason why `executeScript` has to be called after the complete load of the webpage.

So I've done this test:

```
    public class EarlyWebEngineTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        // Early call of executeScript to get a JavaScript object, a proxy for the 
        // Java object to be accessed on the JavaScript environment
        JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("app", new JavaApplication());

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov,oldState,newState)->{
            if(newState==State.SCHEDULED){
                System.out.println("state: scheduled");
            } else if(newState==State.RUNNING){
                System.out.println("state: running");
            } else if(newState==State.SUCCEEDED){
                System.out.println("state: succeeded");
            }
        });

        Button button=new Button("Load Content");
        button.setOnAction(e->webEngine.loadContent("<html>"
                + " <script>function initialize() {"
                + " var nameVar = \"This is a JS var\"; " 
                + " app.callJavascript(nameVar);"
                + "} </script>"
                + "    <body onLoad=\"initialize()\">Hi, this is a test!</body>"
                + "</html>"));

        VBox vbox = new VBox(10,button,webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox,400,300);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public class JavaApplication {

        public void callJavascript(String msg){
            System.out.println("JS>> "+msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The content is not loaded until the button is clicked, but we've already created the JavaScript object on the browser.

Before clicking the button, there's nothing on the output console. But if we click the button... this is the output:

```
state: scheduled
state: running
JS>> This is a JS var
state: succeeded
```

As we can see, the Java object is effectively passed to the script before the latter is executed, and `app.callJavascript` is successfully called while the content is being loaded.

Note that for the common purpose of accessing the loaded DOM, the usual approach of calling `executeScript` after `State.SUCCEEDED` is still the recommended way.

Comment: This only works for the first page loaded, though. The bridge doesn't work for subsequent pages.

Answer (score 2):

Woks for all (including subsequent) pages:
Where "java" is set in JAVA code:

```
window.setMember("java", new JavaApplication());
```

HTML (subsequent) page, keep waiting for 100ms if var "java" is not set (externally by JAVA):

```
 <script>                   
        function init(){
            if (typeof java !== 'undefined') {
                java.doSomething();
            }else{
                setTimeout(function(){ init() }, 100 );
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){           
            init();         
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, loadworker always execute after `window.onload` or `document.onload`.

The workaround you can try, you can create new listener in javascript, for example so-called:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    MyJavaBridge.executeJavaMethod();
});
```

And then in your loadworker, you can do this:

```
webview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
            
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        JSObject window = (JSObject) webview.getEngine().executeScript("window");
        System.out.println("window : " + window);
        window.setMember("MyJavaBridge", javaBridge);
        
        webview.getEngine().executeScript("const event = new Event('deviceready');document.dispatchEvent(event);");
    }
});
```

As you can see, you execute this `webview.getEngine().executeScript("const event = new Event('deviceready');document.dispatchEvent(event);");` after `setMember`, so instead of initialise your work in `window.onload`, you can do it in your custom event listener `deviceready`, so you can have better control on the sequence of page load and java side loadworker.

This is exactly how cordova doing, this idea is coming from it.

[JQuery document.ready vs Phonegap deviceready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready)