# passing values to JavaFX from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps-api-3, javafx, google-polyline

As this is my first post  , forgive any inaccuracies. My problem , i want to pass the value from an javascript function to Javafx on the initialize method

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("googlemaps.html");
    System.out.println("fjdsoij");
    browser.getEngine().load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine(); 
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>(){

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if(newState == State.SUCCEEDED){
                        JSObject window = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        window.setMember("app", new JavaApplication());

                    }
                }
            });
}

public class JavaApplication{
    public void calljavascript( int lengthInMeters){

        System.out.println(lengthInMeters);
    }
}
```

}

and the javascript part is like this

```
   function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, 157.821856)

  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
     //geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
var lengthInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(flightPath.getPath());

  flightPath.setMap(map);
   alert("polyline is "+lengthInMeters+" long");
   app.calljavascript(lengthInMeters);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The value i want to pass is the lengthInMeters  on the method calljavascript any ideas ? thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a simplified version of your code:

```
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov,oldState,newState)->{
        if(newState==State.SUCCEEDED){
            JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            window.setMember("app", new JavaApplication());
        }
    });
    webView.getEngine().loadContent("<html>\n"
            + " <script>function initialize() {"
            + " var lengthInMeters = 5; " 
            + " app.calljavascript(lengthInMeters);"
            + "} </script> "
            + "    <body onLoad=\"initialize()\">Hi!\n"
            + "    </body>\n"
            + "</html>");
```

and it's not working.

In your case and in my approach, `setMember()` is called **after** the web has been loaded, so `initialize()` is called **before** by the `load` method. Consequently, `app.calljavascript()` fails.

The solution is this:

```
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
    window.setMember("app", new JavaApplication());

    browser.getEngine().loadContent("<html>\n"
            + " <script>function initialize() {"
            + " var lengthInMeters = 5; " 
            + " app.calljavascript(lengthInMeters);"
            + "} </script> "
            + "    <body onLoad=\"initialize()\">Hi!\n"
            + "    </body>\n"
            + "</html>");
```

Notice we set the member **before** the web content is loaded.

**EDIT**

I've created a more elaborated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720078/3956070).

Comment: yap that was the solution exactly now everything works fine , thank you man :)

Comment: this does not work on consequent load calls. it is not possible to set the members before loading any more. is there a better solution?

Comment: Please, post a new question refering to this solution

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: There's a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903154/javafx-webview-callback-from-javascript-failing-after-garbage-collection) since Java 8u101. `new JavaApplication()` should be defined in a private field to prevent the Garbage Collection from deleting it. A local variable will seem to work at first but will randomly stop working.

Comment: I've having the same issue as @mohamnag, the bridge works for the first page load but not subsequent ones.