# TypeError in JavaFX WebView

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

I am `registering` my `Java Object` as Given below

```
engine = webView.getEngine();
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                jsobj.setMember("iLink", new IndexLink(this));
                webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
            }
        }
});
```

Sometimes this works well but sometimes it's showing 
**`"TypeError: iLink.getDemoTable is not a function. (In 'iLink.getDemoTable()', 'iLink.getDemoTable' is undefined) (index.js,7)"`**

Can anyone tell me what steps I am `missing` or `anything wrong` in the **`above code`**?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think that anyone will be able to answer your question since the code example you added is not sufficient. Take a look at how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case how should we know, what  `getDemoTable()` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903154/javafx-webview-callback-from-javascript-failing-after-garbage-collection)

And did below changes

> link=new IndexLink(this); in initialize method of controller

```
engine = webView.getEngine();
link=new IndexLink(this);
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
        if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
            jsobj.setMember("iLink", link);
            webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

> jsobj.setMember("iLink", link); and this change on Worker SUCCEEDED

Everything is working fine after that.