# Does JavaFX8 WebEngine's executeScript("window") method refer to the JavaScript window object?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, jsobject

I'm wondering about this code snippet I'm using:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
JSObject jsobj;
webEngine = webView.getEngine();
try {
    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("index.html").toExternalForm());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
    jsobj.setMember("java", new DataModel());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

This line `webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("index.html").toExternalForm());` loads my `index.html` into the `WebView`. Since it is a single page application, that's all I need and there are no more questions about it.
**Now to get back to the question in the title:**
Does this line: `jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");` set the `JSObject` reference to the ["window object" as it's defined by w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)?
Meaning that `jsobj` is now equal to the window object, that *represents the open window in the browser*?
If so: Is this likely to be the reason why my application won't work if I use "reload page" over the context menu in the `WebView`, since it would generate a new `window object`? 
Bonus question: In my JavaScript I can acces the model using `java.methodName();` is "java" here an *identifier* or how would I call it? It's not exactly an *instance*, so I wouldn't call it like this.

Edit:
This is my Java class:

```
public class DataModel{
    public void alert(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

From my JavaScript, which is embedded in `index.html` I can call `java.alert("hello world");` to print `hello world`. Since I'm passing the model reference to the `window object` every function in my JavaScript has access to the `DataModel.class`. From the JavaScript point of view: Is "java." an identifier, reference, instance, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx), `webEngine.executeScript("window")` **would in fact** return the JavaScript Window object. There's also a whole bunch of other code snippet goodies to look!

`java` in this case is a handler that can be used by your JavaScript, within the Window object. So your JavaScript, when referencing `java` can expect to access the `DataModel` object.

Also, you normally want to refresh your page with `location.reload()` in JavaScript.

If you're looking to save state between reloads, you'll want to capture the current HTML and then use the WebView's [loadContent functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-) when the reload is complete. You could also get the WebView's document so you can directly modify nodes at any level.

Comment: Best way to describe it is that java is a reference to an instance of the DataModel class, which when invoked via JavaScript will tunnel through JavaFX to manipulate the class instance in memory (thus calling alert along with the msg you specify). With the link I provided, check out the "Making Upcalls from JavaScript to JavaFX " section.