# Can't get 'deviceready' to work in PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have the following code in my app (Cordova CLI 5.2).

```
<script>  
  var onDeviceReady;

  onDeviceReady = function() {
    alert('device ready');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  };

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
```

However I never see the alert (or background color change) on my Android after I build and install the app using PhoneGap Build. No matter what I do, I can't get this code to work.

Comment: are you using any other libraries that may conflict .. also have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready

Comment: I'm using jQuery and a couple of plugins but they shouldn't conflict. I'll try out the method suggested in the second answer.

Comment: It's almost like PhoneGap Build isn't including cordova.js.

Comment: or something is breaking in a plugin or other included js. I vaguely remember having some conflict in the past because I changed the order of my js includes - is the cordov include in the page ?

Comment: i assume that you are running on a device or simulator and not in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out. I wasn't including phonegap.js in index.html like this:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

D'oh.

Comment: A common mistake. Now you know you'll be able to pass the knowledge on! :)