# Jquery code doesn't work in jQuery mobile project

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm developing an hybrid app with Cordova, using jQuery Mobile libraries.
Since I need to show a map I used and edited the code found [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/map-geolocation/) but seems it doesn't recognize the first line of the code.

Geolocation.js

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#map-page", function() { //doesn't work
    alert('hello');

    function initMap() {
        var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.494887, 11.342616300000032); //Bologna      
        drawMap(defaultLatLng);
    }

     function drawMap(latlng) {
         var myOptions = {
             zoom: 17,
             center: latlng,
         };

         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             title: "Parcheggio"
         });
    }
});
```

Html container is the same as the demo. The scripts I've included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geolocation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD91dMkAWwADchy-WY1-5O7P6nHmjGont0
&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I've also tried to change API key but nothing changes. 
Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You might try the approach in this answer, it provides some good information on where to place your initializing code in a Cordova app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14109006/5633831

Answer (score 0):

You should move the event bindings in `document.ready` block.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#map-page", function() {
      ....
   });
});
```

Additionally, include Geolocation.js after jquery includes.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work. Looks like it doesn't read code starting with $(document) or just $.

Comment: @MonicaKiur - You are including geolocation.js before jquery.js. Need to change the order. Please check now

Comment: I changed the order. Now it works but it's still not loading the map

Comment: @MonicaKiur - Good to know about that. For that I request you to post another question.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MonicaKiur - Happy to help you