# Angular js Integration with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have three questions:

1. What is the best way to integrate AngularJS into Cordova?
2. How do I use the "deviceready" event in Cordova?
3. How should I best bootstrap an AngularJS app to avoid app loading delays?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready I wold use that as a staring spot for hooking your angular app to the cordova. I would suggest doing as much as you can within angular and only use cordova for device access that isn't given to you within the js app (microphone or file system access on iOS for example).

Comment: I have found the issue in device ready  since it it taking time to  boot the app. i have fixed like putting splash image and trying to avoid the loading delay feel. but it's look like temporary fix.