# list view is not loading at initial in jQuery mobile/phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I am trying to make the list. it doesn't appear when I open this page. the list appears after I refresh the opened page
Script to :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var url="/appSample/getgroups.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            var groupId=field.groupId;
            var groupName=field.groupName;
            var createdON=field.createdON;

            $("#listview").append("<a class='item' href='triplist.html'><h3>"+ groupName + " </h3><p>"+ createdON +"</p></a>");

        });
        $('#listview').listview('refresh');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list" id="listview"></ul>
```

Comment: you need to use `deviceready` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready

Comment: i tried @chiliNUT but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

**$(window).bind("load", function()**

instead of:

**$(document).ready(function()** ?

Comment: can you please tell me the value of *console.log(result)*?

Comment: there is a bunch of errors says: uncaught module cordava-plugin-*