# Cordova 2.1: how to check whether runs on device or pc browser?

Tags: javascript, cordova

What is the best way, in javascript, to check if my Cordova application is running in device or in my pc browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser)