# Creating ad supported web application with PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, cordova, ads

I'm getting pretty close to finishing a web application utilizing jQuery mobile and was wondering if anyone could help me out with how they create (optional) ad supported web apps with PhoneGap. As far as I can tell, you have to put the ads at the native app level because obviously if they were in the web app, you wouldn't be able to have an ad free version.

My main question is, what are your methods for stopping people from just browsing to the URL that the PhoneGap webviews are pointing to? Is there some kind of detection mechanism that would allow me to redirect traffic if it's not coming from a PhoneGap app (as opposed to a mobile device browsing via a native browser)? I would prefer to only allow access through these "native" PhoneGap apps.

So far I've found these three links ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347539/detect-between-a-mobile-browser-or-a-phonegap-application), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser), [3](http://bennolan.com/2011/08/22/phonegap-detection.html)), but was curious as to how the SO community approaches this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.