# Detect if running inside PhoneGap/ Cordova

Tags: cordova, native, detect

There has been a few questions how to detect an HTML page is running inside a device as a phonegap application.

Most of the solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347539/detect-between-a-mobile-browser-or-a-phonegap-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser)) have been

1. Detect if browser agent is iPhone/iPad/Android/Blackberry
2. Use 'deviceready' event to detect if running inside a device.
3. Use URL to detect whether protocol is HTTP or FILE

Are there any other solutions? All 3 won't work for me since I run the development HTML files locally before compiling the app, as a result it will detect 1). and 2). will fire and 3). is indeed FILE protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In local file and mobile website deviceready won't fire as it is a PhoneGap specific event. so u can set your IsRunningOnPhoneGap flag in the device ready event.

Comment: DeviceReady fires if the cordova.js file is loaded and the listener is placed. This won't help use the same code for the web and the cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if (window.cordova)
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onReady, false);
}
else 
{
    onReady();
}
```