# How to make Ripple trigger PhoneGap specific code

Tags: javascript, cordova, ripple

I am building a PhoneGap app that also needs to run as a website. When running as a PhoneGap app I have to include the phonegap.js script, but when I run as a website that file won't exist. There are [many ways to accomplish this as covered in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser) My problem is that I'm using the Ripple emulator to test my app in the browser, but most of the tests do not detect Ripple as being PhoneGap. For example; testing for "file:" in the url doesn't work if the page I'm testing in Ripple is served over "http:".

My question is; which technique for conditionally performing code when in PhoneGap will also work when tested in Ripple over http? Does it even matter? Does Ripple always load the phonegap.js file or do I still need to manually include it with a  tag?

Comment: what code do you want to run in PhoneGap but not browser?

Comment: when in PhoneGap I want to wait for deviceready to initialize, when not I can just do it on domready. Also, I didn't want to try to load the phonegap.js file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: hmm, I don't use Ripple, I just test in Chrome (i.e. open my index.html) and the js log shows the deviceready event is caught -- you could just try that. But I don't know for Ripple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a solution for you, but if you're looking for a way to run code conditionally in Ripple, a crude way is to see if your page is being included inside another frame (since Ripple runs your site inside another frame and this is likely a condition unique to Ripple vs. running on a device).  For example, Ripple was constantly alerting that all my plugins weren't supported (ie. Google Analytics Plugin), so to shut it up I did this:

```
if (window.self === window.top){ 
    //not in a frame 
    var in_ripple = 0;
} else { 
    var in_ripple = 1;
}

if (!in_ripple){
    ga_plugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
    ga_plugin.init(...);
}
```