# device is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Using an existing sencha project and PhoneGap Build, I have the problem that `window.device` is not defined if I query for it in the `microloader/testing.js` code.

```
Ext.blink = function(options) {
    ...
    Ext.microloaded = true;
    // Start my microloader enhancement
    isPhonegap = typeof window.device != "undefined";
    window.alert("isPhonegap: " + isPhonegap);
```

The config.xml contains the plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
```

Sencha is uploading everything to PhoneGap Build for me, it is built there, and then I download and `adb install -r` the resulting apk on my Android 4.0.4 Smartphone.

Result when starting the app, is the alert: `isPhonegap: false`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing a bit here, but could it be that you're calling that code before `deviceReady` has fired?

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready for details.

Comment: As of now, I am using window.device to find out whether the app is running in phonegap container or in a real browser.Now I guess I have to find another way, because I should only wait for a deviceReady if I am in a phonegap container, right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.
But there's another thread on SO that has some ideas for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser