# document.location() function given in the .js code works fine in Internet Explorer but does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jsp, firefox

`document.location()` function given in the `logn.js` code works fine in Internet Explorer but does not work in Firefox. The given js code is for implementing AJAX in the login page .. AJAX directs the code to a servlet which if login OK gives user Login as response.

**logn.js**

```
function logn(emailId,password) {
    var parameters="emailId="+emailId+"&password="+password;
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {    // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {     
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.toString()=="User Login") {     
                document.location("userhome.jsp"); 
            } else if(xmlhttp.responseText.toString()=="Admin Login") { 
                document.location("adminhome.jsp"); 
            }else {
                //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }       
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "LoginServlet", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);   
}
```

**the following is the servlet code LoginServlet.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String emailId=request.getParameter("emailId");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");



        if (emailId.isEmpty()||password.isEmpty()) { 
            out.write("Please enter EmailId/Password");
        } else {
            LoginModel lm=new LoginModel();
            lm.setEmailId(emailId);
            lm.setPassword(password);

            LoginService ls=new LoginService();
            lm=(LoginModel) ls.loginCheck(lm);

            if(lm!=null){
                System.out.println("login ok");
                HttpSession session =request.getSession();
                System.out.println(lm.getLoginId());
                session.setAttribute("userlogin", lm);

                if (lm.getIsAdmin()==0) {
                    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaa");
                    out.write("User Login");
                }
                else if (lm.getIsAdmin()==1) 
                    out.write("Admin Login");

                ls.setIsActive(lm.getLoginId(),1);
            } else 
                out.write("Wrong EmailId/Password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have firebug installed in firefox so see what errors are occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using:

```
window.location = "userhome.jsp";
```

and

```
window.location = "adminhome.jsp";
```

There were a couple issues with how you were doing it.  It's preferred to use `window.location` instead of `document.location`.  And, you assign to it, not call it like a function.

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: What is the difference between window.location and document.location ?

Comment: @AlanFoster - As you have discovered, there are cross browser compatibility issues with document.location and it is read-only in some browsers.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip

Answer (score 1):

instead of document.location() try:

```
document.location.href = ...
```