# What is the best way to access the location object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Which of the following should I use to assign the `location` object to a local variable in javascript?

```
var l = location;
var l = window.location;
var l = window.document.location;
```

Why are there so many methods? Is there any difference?

Comment: @Xander the duplicate has a comment referring to a better duplicate, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip/2431375#2431375

Comment: @Xander Thanks! That answer is helpful. I voted to close my own question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `window.location`, to help ensure I was really talking about the global object's property, and not some local variable which happens to be called `location`.

The [W3C specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location) say:

> The location attribute of the Window interface must return the Location object for that Window object's Document.

so those two are indeed equivalent (in fact exactly the same object).

`location` just happens to be a short hand for `window.location`, so long as there's no other variable named `location` in the scope.

Comment: what if `window` is some local variable?

Comment: @Esailija that's indeed possible, as I'm sure you know, but you can't insure against stupidity...  That's why I said _help_ ensure.

Comment: Yes you can, `new Function( "return this;")().location`, anything less and you might as well use `location` directly :P

Comment: the w3c spec speaks there about the window.location attribute. not the document.location attribute. big differences and problems can occur if you assume they are the same.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets yeah, I'm trying to understand thay myself - since `document` **is** `window.document` it's unclear exactly what the distinction is.

Comment: Window.document refers to the first loaded document. basically the url you typed. however document.location can refer to a whole different url if your page has been framed. why this is? by window.document.location you go down a specific ladder. by taking document.location you dont care where on the ladder you are.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I think you're confusing `window.document.location` with `parent.document.location` in the iframe case.

Comment: @Esailija `(1,eval)("this").location` works too and is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

They all refer to the same object. Though, `window.location` is more explicit, cross browser compliant and can prevent collisions with other variables named `location` in different scopes.

> Why so many ways?

Browser differences/vestigial remnants from a bygone era.

Comment: They do not refer to same object. they are same types, but they do differ. See my answer

Comment: @Xander - Cowards!  I'll give you an upvote so you can at least get a net 8.

Answer (score 0):

In a web browser, `window` is always at the top of the variable lookup chain. Thus, a global variable `x` is also `window.x`.  For example:

```
<script>
var x = 1;
window.alert(window.x);
</script>
```

Will alert `1`.  Similarly, `location` will also resolve as `window.location` provided there is no *more local* variable called `location` in the chain.

Comment: @Xander - Correct, if `x` exists within the local scope of a function, it will not be a property of `window`.  Thus, `window` is perhaps a better way to fully qualify a global version of `location` if there was also a local variable called `location`.  Provided, of course, there's not *also* a local variable called `window` :)

Answer (score -1):

window.location is the _top location.
document.location is the current html page location

if you are in an iframe document.location of the iframe will differ because window.location refers to the parent page.

by having a check on this you can break from frames by checking if the are te same. if not break from unauthorised framing.
or check if my parent page for the i frame is the right one, if not redirect to the right one.

Comment: I don't think so, provide a jsfiddle. I get `document.location === window.location` no matter what iframe I am in

Comment: Its classic location checking. you might want to add .href to you location attribute. if(document.location.href != window.location.href) window.location.href=document.location.href;this code has worked for me since 1998 to prevent illegal framing.

Comment: Since they are objects, and the equality test gives true, this means that they point to exactly the same object in memory. How could .href be different for them?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets are you _sure_ you're not thinking of `parent.document.location` ?