# How do we update URL or query strings using javascript/jQuery without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to update the URL programatically without reloading the page?

EDIT: I added something in the title in post .I just want to make it clear that I don't want to reload the page

Comment: Give an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: do you want to change the visible URL (in address-bar) or the document URL string in the DOM?

Comment: @Maurice I just want to change the visible URL

Comment: use **window.history.replaceState( )** as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49493091/3128521)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes - `document.location = "http://my.new.url.com"`

You can also retrieve it the same way eg.

```
var myURL = document.location;
document.location = myURL + "?a=parameter";
```

The location object has a number of useful properties too:

```
hash            Returns the anchor portion of a URL
host            Returns the hostname and port of a URL
hostname        Returns the hostname of a URL
href            Returns the entire URL
pathname        Returns the path name of a URL
port            Returns the port number the server uses for a URL
protocol        Returns the protocol of a URL
search          Returns the query portion of a URL
```

**EDIT:**
Setting the hash of the document.location shouldn't reload the page, just alter where on the page the focus is. So updating to `#myId` will scroll to the element with `id="myId"`. If the `id` doesn't exist I believe nothing will happen? (Need to confirm on various browsers though)

**EDIT2:** To make it clear, not just in a comment:
You can't update the whole URL with javascript without changing the page, this is a security restriction. Otherwise you could click on a link to a random page, crafted to look like gmail, and instantly change the URL to www.gmail.com and steal people's login details.
You can change the part after the domain on some browsers to cope with AJAX style things, but that's already been linked to by Osiris. What's more, you probably shouldn't do this, even if you could.  The URL tells the user where he/she is on your site. If you change it without changing the page contents, it's becomes a little confusing.

Comment: I am looking at updating all of the url, not just hashes

Comment: You can't update the whole URL with javascript without changing the page, this is a security restriction. Otherwise you could click on a link to a random page, and instantly have the URL say www.gmail.com and steal people's logins.

Comment: Setting `document.location` reloads the page.

Comment: Thanks @AlainTiemblo - if you read the whole answer you will see that I acknowledge that, with the caveats I already stated.

Comment: Good deep explanation.

Comment: No - the answer is yes - just not the whole URL - the URL begin formed of the protocol, host, optional port, folder structure, page, query parameters and page location.  It's possible to alter the page location `#blah` as described.

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? This reloads the page. Answer should be deleted.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie Because it is correct?  You can update parts of the URL (thus updating the URL) (Such as the # section) without reloading the page. Why should this answer be deleted?

Answer (score 95):

Yes and no. All the common web browsers has a security measure to prevent that. The goal is to prevent people from creating replicas of websites, change the URL to make it look correct, and then be able to trick people and get their info.

However, some HTML5 compatible web browsers has implemented an History API that can be used for something similar to what you want:

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?myNewUrlQuery=1';
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

I tested, and it worked fine. It does not reload the page, but it only allows you to change the URL query. You would not be able to change the protocol or the host values.

For more information:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Clicking "back"  will remove changes but I like the idea.

Comment: This approach does not work in some browsers because `window.location.pathname` contains a trail slash `/`, and result value could be `http://my.domain.com/?myNewUrlQuery=1` instead of `http://my.domain.com?myNewUrlQuery=1`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use :

```
window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', newUrlWithQueryString)
```

Comment: or window.history.replaceState('obj', 'newtitle', newUrlWithQueryString) if you do not want to have the url change saved in history.

Answer (score 5):

Use

> window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, updatedUri);

To update Url **without reloading** the page

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 var urlParts = url.split('?');
 if (urlParts.length > 0) {
     var baseUrl = urlParts[0];
     var queryString = urlParts[1];

     //update queryString in here...I have added a new string at the end in this example
     var updatedQueryString = queryString + 'this_is_the_new_url' 

     var updatedUri = baseUrl + '?' + updatedQueryString;
     window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, updatedUri);
 }
```

To remove Query string **without reloading** the page

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
     var updatedUri = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
     window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, updatedUri);
}
```

Comment: I was just looking at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) for `window.history.replaceState()` I'm unsure of what the three parameters do, can you explain that? The second, specifically `document.title` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `replaceState()` operates exactly like `pushState()` so check the descriptions of the [parameters for the `pushState()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method).
 `title` parameter is ignored for now, but they might use it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Define a new URL object, assign it the current url, append your parameter(s) to that URL object and finally push it to your browsers state.

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
//var url = new URL(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname) <- flush existing parameters
url.searchParams.append("order", orderId);
window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes

document.location is the normal way.

However document.location is effectively the same as window.location, except for window.location is a bit more supported in older browsers so may be the prefferable choice.

Check out this thread on SO for more info:

[What's the difference between window.location and document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip)

Answer (score 1):

Prefix URL changes with a hashtag to avoid a redirect.

This redirects

```
location.href += '&test='true';
```

This doesn't redirect

```
location.href += '#&test='true';
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain javascript: document.location = 'http://www.google.com';

This will cause a browser refresh though - consider using hashes if you're in need of having the URL updated to implement some kind of browsing history without reloading the page. You might want to look into jQuery.hashchange if this is the case.

Comment: Yep, it causes a browser refresh. Was looking for something that does not reload.

Comment: It should be possible to do without page refreshes but it's only supported in newer browsers as far as I know. You should go for the hash url changing instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be more specific. What do you mean by 'update the URL'?  It could mean automatically navigating to a different page, which is certainly possible.

If you want to just update the contents of the address bar without reloading the page, see [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am looking at the answers

Answer (score -3):

Yes - `document.location.hash` for queries

Comment: It reloads the page. I am looking for a solution that doesn't remove the page.

Comment: Yes, of cause, it reloads page. You need to combine this with ajax in order to get new page and insert its content.

Comment: The person asking the question does not want to reload the page.