# jQuery document.location.href if, else if and else

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know **else if** works on jQuery so where's the problem in this code:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('#1')) {
    $(".products li").fadeIn();
}
else if (document.location.href === '#2') {
    $(".products li").fadeOut();
    $(".products li.2").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
}
else if (document.location.href === '#3') {
    $(".products li").fadeOut();
    $(".products li.3").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
}
else if (document.location.href === '#4') {
    $(".products li").fadeOut();
    $(".products li.4").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
}
else if (document.location.href === '#5') {
    $(".products li").fadeOut();
    $(".products li.5").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
}
else if (document.location.href === '#6') {
    $(".products li").fadeOut();
    $(".products li.6").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
}
else {
    $(".products li").fadeIn();
}
```

If i put only **if** instead of **else if** it works but it's not correct.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: [The correct object is `window.location`, not `document.location` -- although both will work in modern browsers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascript)

Comment: I've got a clickable list with different categories, when you click a category it'll display only the products with that category Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `document.location.href.indexOf('#1')` [will return -1 if no match is found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), and zero if it matches at the start of the string. Since you test for falsey values, you'll never have a false result (-1 evaluates as a Boolean `true`). You should have written:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('#1')>-1) {
```

But since you appear to be comparing hashes, let's just do those directly instead (and use the [proper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.location) `window.location` while we're at it):

```
if (window.location.hash == '#1') {
    // ...
} else if (window.location.hash == '#2') {
    // etc.
```

That said, in your case, we can do this entirely without the `if/else` just by parsing that hash string:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1); // remove leading #
if (hash) {
    $(".products li").fadeOut();
    $(".products li."+hash).stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
} else {
    $(".products li").fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your last solution it's pretty amazing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to check for the hashvalue in the url, so why don't you use

`location.hash`

since `location.href` includes the whole url

Comment: Yeah, what I want is to check for the hashvalue in the url.
If I use location.hash the first if it changes like this
if (window.location.hash === '#1') ?

Comment: Yes, but Blazemonger explained it beautifully in his answer. Just go with what he explained.

Answer (score 0):

in the first if you are using indexOf:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('#1'))
```

But in the other else if you don't use it but rather you compare the href.location itself:

```
else if (document.location.href === '#2')
```

Comment: Probably OP meant to use `document.location.hash` instead.