# javascript - window.location or document.location

Tags: javascript, object, browser

Is there any difference between the location property of the window object versus the location property of the document object?

```
window.location || document.location  // That is the question.
```

- Are their properties identical?
- Do they have differing browser support?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the link. [@Christoph's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2431375/552067) was insightful. Voted to close my question.

Answer (score 0):

These two objects are identical:

```
console.log(window.location === document.location) // true
```

They both refer to Location object.

Comment: Why are there two ways to access the same object?

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location represent position in current view of page in browser window
```

and `document.location` represents position in currently displaying full document/page

e.g in http://www.nationalgeographic.com/ upto DAILY NEWS section is `window` and full page scrolled down till end is `document`