# URL Redirection to subdomain of another domain

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

I have two domains as: `project1.com` and `project2.com`. The latter contains a subdomain as `login.project2.com`. I need to redirect a user to this place, i.e. `login.project2.com` from the former based on his input. (Don't ask about the logic, or as to why I do this, it is simply because I have been asked to do).

I have tried the following:

```
function redirectToPage() {
    if (someVar == someValue) {
        document.location = 'http://www.login.project2.com'; // does not work
        document.location = 'www.login.project2.com'; // does not work
        document.location = 'http://login.project2.com'; // does not work
        document.location = 'login.project2.com'; // inval

        //only of the above is left uncommented at a time
    }
}
```

But, when I type the fourth one directly in the address bar, it leads me to the desired page. Where am I wrong?

Comment: [Use window.location instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip)

Comment: Use window.location.href= 'login.project2.com'

Comment: @new_developer - not without the protocol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. document.location is deprecated and could be read-only
2. if you have another domain, you need the protocol too. this is added by the browser if you leave it out on the location bar, but not in a script.
3. it is good practice to wrap a statement in brackets so I added them for you

Here is how to redirect using JavaScript - I use replace so the old address is replaced in the history so the back button is not broken

```
function redirectToPage() {
  if (someVar == someValue) {
    window.location.replace('http://login.project2.com'); 
  }
}
```