# jQuery function works selectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am trying to implement some simple javascript in my iOS app. I inject the javascript using the usual method

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
```

However, a script as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       alert(document.location);
       });
```

seems to work on some websites (for example www.nytimes.com), but not on others such as www.latimes.com. The function above is ridiculously simple and I expect it to work uniformly everywhere. Does anyone know a reason for this behavior?

Comment: How exactly are you running this script on those sites?

Comment: okay, I perhaps need to provide more information. Let me adjust the question itself

Comment: any chance related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip

Comment: I don't think I am me/issing with window or document locations here.

Comment: From the console of a browser on a normal PC, your code snipper works on both www.nytimes.com and www.latimes.com for me (assuming I add jQuery to the page first, of course!). I trust you're including jQuery? Can you provide steps to reproduce the issue you're having?

Comment: What do you get when it doesn't work ? `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'` ?

Comment: @MarkAmery: I usually check if the page already has jQuery or not, in the latter case I add it from the CDN. Now, I may be doing something wrong if I check existence of jQuery by the function

`if(jQuery)
     return 1;`

Comment: Okay, I dropped the jQuery check function and now add jQuery always... it works well now :)...

I hope adding jQuery redundantly is not a performance-unfriendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will depend on the existance of jQuery in the ressources of the site (scripts), otherwise I would resort to `alert(window.location);` which is pure JS and it will uniformally work fine.