# Trying to add a class to element if URL contains X

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to get to work this bit of a code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('product') > -1){
    $('.featproducts').addClass("display-none")
}
});
</script>
```

The URL is:
http://domsveta.by/katalog/product/3919-

Here's some test fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/83H63/5/

I'm afraid it's in Russian so it's gonna create some complecations in understanding.

Any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks

I want to assign a class `.display-none` to any the element of class `"featproducts"` if it is shown on the page with `"product"` in the URL

**UPDATE**

In the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/83H63/5/
Using the `#` I was able to add a class to an element

However on the production site I wasn't able to do it using either `#` or `.featproducts`

**So it's not the code that's faily.**

Thank you for your heads up.

Comment: The selector is wrong.

Comment: can we see the edited code in your question? and can you also paste the page URL or something similar? I am nearly sure that the issue is with your IF cond.

Comment: @LShetty I've just edited the question. Added a dot before in the ``'featproducts'`` selector so it's now ``'.featproducts'``. Nothing changed. The URL is http://domain.com/katalog/product/XXXX where XXXX is the ID of the product.

Comment: right, now post the relevant HTML

Comment: and if you do alert($('.featproducts').length) just before the if conditon, what do you get?

Comment: @LShetty created a small fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/83H63/2/

Comment: @LShetty still nothing is shown in the console.

Comment: @goodknight: your code actually works, check: http://jsfiddle.net/83H63/6/ (I've changed "product" to "_display" as this is part of the url of the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

[class selector `.`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('.featproducts').addClass("display-none");
// ^
```

Comment: Edited the code still not working. No error in the console is shown.

Comment: ``.display-none{
 display: none;
``}

Comment: @TusharGupta the console prints "null".

Comment: @TusharGupta but there is. At least the source code says so.

Comment: then why does console log says null ??

Comment: @goodknight: do you call jquery? because in the fiddle you didn't

Comment: @Vickel yes I do on the production site of course. I didnt do that in the fiddle since the code is not supposed to work there as it will have nothing to do with the URL provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` to target class in jQuery, so you can do:

```
$('.featproducts').addClass("display-none");
```

Answer (score 0):

Gosh! how could I not see it...

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/83H63/8/)
Ignore the alert, hit "run"

it has to be:

```
window.location.href


if ( window.location.href.indexOf('product') > -1){
    $('.featproducts').addClass("display-none")
}
```

Comment: According to the W3C, they are the same. In reality, for cross browser safety, you should use window.location rather than document.location see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip