# Is there a JavaScript method that will allow me to give the body a certain css class depending on which html page the user is on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to track what the URL the user is on and add a remove a class based on that URL. Can someone help me out?

**Edit***

This is what I have right now and my page is just reloading

```
var $webPage = "http://localhost/collin-sanderson/";

    if (location.href = $webPage) {
        $('body').addClass('home')
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('home')
    }
```

Comment: The question title does not have any relation with whatever you are asking.

Comment: Which problem do you have? You don't know how to get the url of the page? You don't know how to add classes? You don't know how to add one class or another depending on the url once you got it?

Comment: I don't know how to add one class or another depending on the url once I have it.

Comment: First off because you are checking if it equals. It should be == instead of just =. When you say just = it is an assignment operator whereas == is a comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks, missed that! It's working just how I want now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $webPage = "http://localhost/collin-sanderson/";

    if (location.href == $webPage) {
        $('body').addClass('home')
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('home')
    }
```

I have altered the code so it uses a comparison operator instead of an assignment operator. Assignment operators are used to write a value to a variable, on the other hand a comparison operator compares two variables like you require. See [JavaScript Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Also here is a helpful/interesting read on the difference between document and window objects. [Difference between document and window objects](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/).

Comment: Lol downvote for trying to help without an IDE... sweet *thumbs up*

Comment: Or window.location See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip

Comment: Both work. Also @ianaya it is capital if you check the documentation.

Comment: The advantage of `location` is that you can access the different parts: `location.pathname`, `location.host`, `location.href`, ...

Comment: There you go, might be better to use .location which can also be used via the document object or windows. But before you decide which object to use here is an interesting and helpful read http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/