# How can I make a redirect page by browser using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, browser

Is it possible to redirect a user that use a specific browser to a different link, using jQuery (or JavaScript)?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1)
    {
        document.location = "http://other/page.com/";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just a pointer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip

Comment: @Seram I cannot understand the difference...it's best practice using `window.location` but why?

Comment: just wanted you to check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it OK, but you have syntax error - one extra left brace, remove the one before `navigator`:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1)
    {
        document.location = "http://other/page.com/";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following to redirect:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: As I wrote I need to redirect only users that are using a specific browser

Answer (score 1):

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;   // At least IE6
if(isIE){
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Check browser: [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: checking for User agent string to determine browser is not really a good way.