# How to open a website in the same tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs

So I am trying to make a tab system for my website and I have been using `window.open("The Website")` except when I use it, the site opens on a new tab. Is there a way to make it open on the same tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign to `window.location`, then the current window will load a new URL in that tab:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com";
```

See [What's the difference between window.location and document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip) for why it is slightly safer (for cross browser compatibility) to use `window.location` instead of `document.location`, though in most browsers you can use either.

Comment: Would I still need the brackets around the quotes?

Comment: @StigCoder - I don't understand what you're asking.  You assign a string URL to `window.location`.

Comment: @StigCoder No, you don't need the parentheses around the quotes.  `window.open` is a function, so you call it with parentheses - `window.open(url)`.  `window.location` is not a function, you assign a string to it with the `=` assignment operator as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.location = "your_url"
```

or

```
window.location = "your_url";
```

or you can use jQuery to create link and then click on it

```
var link $('<a href="your_url" style="display: none;">x</a>');
$('body').append(link);
link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = $('<iframe src="yoursite.com"></iframe>');
$(document).append(iframe);
```

Comment: Although technically, yes, this opens the site "in" (as in "somewhere within") the same tab, this is not the answer to the question.  It's also not complete, you would need to at least set dimensions on that `iframe` element.