# Passing document.location in Analytics event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm measuring submissions of a form that appears on multiple pages as an Analytics event. I want to pass the `document.location` of the current page in an Analytics event.

Here is what I tried:

```
1. onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'email2', 'signup', document.location);"
2. onClick="var _loc = document.location;ga('send', 'event', 'email2', 'signup', #&39;_loc#&39;);"
```

In situation #1 the event label passed in Analytics is `document.location` and not the actual URL

In situation #2 the event wasn't passed to Analytics

Note that I'm using Universal Analytics

[Reference for event tracking](https://gaconfig.com/google-analytics-event-tracking/newsletter-signup/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual URL of the page is `window.location.href`.

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'email2', 'signup', window.location.href);"
```

`document.location` and `window.location` are objects, not the URL itself.  If you want to pass the URL, not the location object, then you should fetch the `.href` property as shown above.

Though `doucment.location` and `window.location` both have the info you want, you probably want to use `window` as the source of the info, not `document`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip) for use of `window.location` vs. `document.location`.