# How to run CookieList (MODx extension) with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, modx, modx-revolution

Please, explain to me how to run snippet CookieList with ajax?

I tried next:
1. Created snippet ajaxCookieList:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $values = $modx->runSnippet('addToCookieLIst',array(
        'value' => $_POST['action']
    ));
    $output = $modx->runSnippet('pdoResources',[
            'parents' => 6,
            'resources' => $values,
            'tpl' => 'popup.favorites.item',
            'includeTVs' => 'header.bgImage,franchise.logo,franchise.price,title,subtitle',
            'prepareTVs' => '1',
            'hideContainers' => '1'
        ]);
    return $output; 
}
```

2. Then i created chunk with this code:

   `<script>
       jQuery(function($){
           $('a.franchise-pin, a.franchise-favorite-add').click(function(e){
               var value = $(this).data('value');
               $.post(document.location.href, {action: value}, function(data) {
                   $('#favorites').html(data);
                   $('#favorites').modal('show');
               });
               e.preventDefault();
           });
       });
   </script>`

But response is all page..

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in such cases:

1. I place a snippet call (`[[!ajaxCookieList]]`) on a service page
   accessible via URL like /page-with-snippet/
2. In JS (ajax) I use that URL to which I send parameters
3. The snippet has to get the parameters I send. So, I really call it like this: `[[!ajaxCookieList? &action=`[[!#POST.action]]`]]`
4. Access to parameters in snippets is possible like this: `$option = $modx->getOption('action', $scriptProperties, 'default_value', true);`
5. I do my stuff in the snippet

But in your case, I think, everything can be simpler. You use one of the pdoTools snippets and **if I am not mistaken**, you can just place pdoResources snippet call on a page (/page-with-snippet/) like this:

```
[[pdoResources?
  &parents=`6`
  &resources=`[[!addToCookieLIst? &value=`[[!#POST.action]]` ]]` // your snippet should return comma-separated list of resources` ids that you pass then to pdoResources
  &tpl=`popup.favorites.item`
  &includeTVs=`header.bgImage,franchise.logo,franchise.price,title,subtitle`
  &prepareTVs=`1`
  &hideContainers=`1`
]]
```

and now you can send parameters to this page (/page-with-snippet/) via AJAX and get the results if there are any. I hope I didn't mess anything - you had better check it again, but you get the idea at least :) BTW, check this [article](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/snippets/how-to-write-a-good-snippet) on modx.com that teaches how to write a good snippet.

Also another minor issue: as it has been pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip), the use of `window.location` is preferable to `document.location`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I did. I used [pdoResources](https://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources). Hope that you will understand my code and customize it for yourselves.

1. Create snippet [ajaxCookieList](https://pastebin.com/uFAfqTNk)
2. Paste [JS-code](https://pastebin.com/emrTwvj6) in your custom.js file
3. Simple markup for resources. Insert it in the chunk:

`<a href="#" data-id=[[+id]] data-action="add">Add to wish list</a>`

`<a href="#" data-id=[[+id]] data-action="remove">Remove from wish list</a>`

Thas all:)