# what's difference between document.URL and window.location?

Tags: javascript, dom

I heard using document.location is not a good idea. window.location is better.

But document.URL performs a similar role.

```
var msg = '<p><b>page title: </b>'+document.title +'<br/>';
msg += '<b>page address: </b>'+document.URL +'<br />';
msg += '<b>page address: </b>'+window.location+'<br/>';
msg += '<b>last modified: </b>'+ document.lastModified + '</p>';

var el = document.getElementById('footer');
el.innerHTML = msg;
```

In my code, document.URL and window.location print out same address.
Any differences between them? When should I use document.URL and when window.location ?

Comment: This would give you a better idea  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip

Comment: @Ashish Are document.location and document.URL  same?